# Client side 100% secure password POST

Tags: javascript, security, post, md5

I came up with this theory to avoid password stealing form POST sniffing.
The idea is to concatenate a salt string (randomly generated on php session_start()).

[image]

**Please, note that the salt_hash is randomly generated on each access... It is NOT calculated in the client side.**

Basically the JS code would be added to the HTML:

```
<script>
var salt_hash='654236426556424655643645462321560356';
</script>
```

then before POSTing it, I'd calculate...

```
cryptoPass = md5(md5(password)+salt_hash);
passowrd = ''; // clear user password input
submit POST...;
```

Then on login.php I'd compare $_POST['cryptoPass'] with md5( MySQL user password stored with md5, plus the salt_hash)

Would it actually work or it's a nonsense theory?

Comment: Having a client side salt is a bad idea.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This is what transport encryption is for. (SSL/TLS)

Comment: @RUJordan: It looks like the salt is generated on the server and stored in session. The client doesn't send the salt to the server.

Comment: @MichaelLiu — Then the server has to send the salt to the client. Either way, it is sniffable.

Comment: @Quentin: Ok... the attacker sniffed all the stream!! he has the salt. Still the server side php session() would invalidate his attempt to use another user's salt, which is random on each call to (session) login.php

Comment: @Azevedo — the session id would be sniffable too, and (as mentioned in answers below) once the salt is known, it is trivial to brute force the original password.

Comment: @Quentin is right. The attacker doesn't even need the session ID (but he could also use session-hijacking to create different attack vectors). Once the attacker has the salt value and the algorithm to create the password hash, the attacker has everything he/she needs to crack the hash.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: because the wheel sometimes heartbleeds...

Comment: This approach is actually less secure than the standard approach.  In this approach you gain nothing above the level of security granted with TLS, however your are forcing the server to store a user's password in plain text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I'll start with a side note, the first rule in security is never try to make and use your own crypto. There are professionals out there that are very good at making cryto algorithms, and people are still able to crack them.

Your scheme does not actually add that much security to the scheme. If an attacker knew that you were calculating hashes with:

> cryptoPass = md5(md5(password)+salt_hash);

Then they could just brute force using the same algorithm if they knew the salt value. This adds almost no security because it takes almost the same time to crack:

> cryptoPass = md5(password + salt);

both of the cracking algorithms for this are the same. They are the same time complexity. You are just hashing using two different functions.

The best solution here would to just be to use TLS, which is easily implemented.

And the notion of **Client side 100% secure *Insert Anything*** is unrealistic. There is no way to secure something 100% unfortunately. If man made it, then with enough time, man can crack it.

---

**Why using hashing + salt on the client side as an encryption mechanism is bad:**

Let's say you use RANDOM hashing, just as you have mentioned. The client initiates a login sequence with the server and the server sends it the salt value:

> 718904732197

The attacker now knows the salt value. Now, the client hashes his/her password using your hashing function:

> cryptoPass = md5(md5(password)+salt_hash);

The salt hash is random, but known and so is the algorithm. From this the attacker cracks the hash using a simple brute force algorithm (it would take a matter of seconds to crack a simple 6 digit password). They can also use rainbow table and dictionary attacks against the hash to increase the cracking speed.

The attacker will generate hashes using your known function:

> cryptoPass = md5(md5(password)+salt_hash);

and they already know the salt value. They will extract the password from the hash using brute force. Now they have the clear text password and probably the username so they can now login to that user's account.

---

Maybe this will help you as well:

Is this better than no security? YES

Is hashing + salt better than hashing alone? YES

Is using a random salt value even more secure? YES, to an extent.

All of that aside, the scheme that you are using is not secure by today's standards. An experienced cracker could have your entire algorithm figured out in a couple of hours.

Comment: What if I put a for() to calculate the MD5 32x? and add interval limit between retries (against brute force)?

Comment: Hashing the password on the client would at least have made it non-trivial to obtain cleartext passwords using the Heartbleed vulnerability.

Comment: what if this salt is **random**?

Comment: @John: You misunderstood my comment. Client-side salting and hashing would have helped protect users' passwords from Heartbleed.

Comment: @MichaelLiu if the salting algorithm is constant and known to the attacker, then that is more secure than not salting, but is still insecure. Salting on the client side would still give the attacker knowledge of the algorithm used to salt the password. The attacker could then just use brute force to crack passwords.

Comment: @Azevedo if you are able to salt the password in a way where the attacker doesn't know the salt value AND/OR he doesn't know how it's salted, then it will make it next to impossible for the attacker to crack the password hash.

Comment: @Azevedo let me give you an example, if you used the day the account was created as a salt value (something the client might know, but the attacker does not), then it will be harder for the attacker to crack the hash.

Comment: @John: that's the point... this method uses a **RANDOM** salt. every call to login.php would be a different salt like 5df3358b514975af57626868697cd672df88de3b.

Comment: @Azevedo If the attacker is able to sniff the salt value, then it doesn't matter. From a security perspective, you have to assume that the attacker will have access to the entire stream of packets. If this were true, the attacker would have access to the salt value. This would add no extra security at all.

Comment: @Azevedo Just use TLS, that way you don't have to worry about how secure your algorithm is. Using salt with no TLS is not going to do you much good.

Comment: @John: Ok... the attacker sniffed all the stream!! he has the salt. Still the server side php session() would invalidate his attempt to use another's user salt, which is random on each call to (session) login.php

Comment: @Azevedo see my explanation I added.

Comment: @John: I see it clearly now. But what if the php's hash generator would be a 128 chars lenght + uses time+date + more complexibility?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51124/discussion-between-azevedo-and-john)